# perl - extracting data from a file on a specific day

Tags: perl

i am new to Perl and I am trying to extract specific data from a file from last 12 days until today. I need a script that will do it every day

date format : day-Month-year, for example: 15-FEB-13 (today)

example of a file:

```
E8:BE:81:86:1E:09;**14-FEB-13**;195.116.227.97       *
00:78:9E:ED:B8:3B;**30-JAN-13**;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:ED:B9:50;**14-FEB-13**;195.116.227.105      *  
00:78:9E:ED:B8:24;**11-FEB-13**;195.116.227.97       *
4C:17:EB:F1:AE:BF;**16-DEC-12**;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:F4:AC:C1;**21-NOV-12**;195.116.227.97
E8:BE:81:87:03:AA;**11-FEB-13**;195.116.227.97

etc .............................................
```

I need data from last 12 days. in the above example marks *

thanks for help in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  SO is not a place to ask for work to be done for you.

Comment: Are the asterisks around the dates part of the data format? And by "the last 12 days" do you mean "today and the previous 11 days" or "today and the previous 12 days"? i.e. 3-Feb onwards or 4-Feb onwards?

Comment: What do the days under ten look like in your file? `5` or `05`?

Answer (score 2):

[`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) is a core module so shouldn't need installing.

This program skips lines with a date before the previous 11 days. If you need the previous 12 days then change `11` to `12`.

You will need to either `open` the input file and use the file handle instead of `DATA`, or put the file name on the command line and use `<ARGV>` instead of `<DATA>`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece 'localtime';
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $limit = localtime() - ONE_DAY * 11;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless my ($date) = /([0-3][0-9]-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2})/;
  $date = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%d-%b-%y');
  print if $date >= $limit;
}

__DATA__
E8:BE:81:86:1E:09;14-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:ED:B8:3B;30-JAN-13;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:ED:B9:50;14-FEB-13;195.116.227.105
00:78:9E:ED:B8:24;11-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
4C:17:EB:F1:AE:BF;16-DEC-12;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:F4:AC:C1;21-NOV-12;195.116.227.97
E8:BE:81:87:03:AA;11-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
```

**output**

```
E8:BE:81:86:1E:09;14-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
00:78:9E:ED:B9:50;14-FEB-13;195.116.227.105
00:78:9E:ED:B8:24;11-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
E8:BE:81:87:03:AA;11-FEB-13;195.116.227.97
```